# Ripple - how to properly set flags?

Tags: transactions, ripple, json-rpc, error

At the moment I'm trying to add flags to my custom Ripple transactions that I submit through JSON RPC. However, when I send my request:

```
{  
   "id":1,
   "method":"sign",
   "params":[  
      {  
         "secret":"sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "tx_json":{  
            "Account":"rfESTMcbvbvCBqU1FTvGWiJP8cmUSu4GKg",
            "Amount":"31000000",
            "Destination":"rUD9V5kvnCpwN9HbZQqCwziMv3vtGgswZF",
            "Flags":2.147483648e+09,
            "LastLedgerSequence":7824714,
            "Sequence":63166,
            "TransactionType":"Payment"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I get such responses:

```
{  
   "result":{  
      "error":"invalidParams",
      "error_code":27,
      "error_message":"Field 'tx_json.Flags' has bad type.",
      "request":{  
         "command":"sign",
         "secret":"sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "tx_json":{  
            "Account":"rfESTMcbvbvCBqU1FTvGWiJP8cmUSu4GKg",
            "Amount":"31000000",
            "Destination":"rUD9V5kvnCpwN9HbZQqCwziMv3vtGgswZF",
            "Flags":2147483648,
            "LastLedgerSequence":7824714,
            "Sequence":63166,
            "TransactionType":"Payment"
         }
      },
      "status":"error"
   }
}
```

Indicating that `Flags` is a bad type. Is it due to `Flags` in my request being sent in a float format (even though the response properly interprets it), or is it something else?

Comment: Probably wouldn't be that hard to test to find out the issue. You can also use the API tool for testing. https://ripple.com/tools/api/#submit

Answer (score 2):

The error message explains the program. The `Flags` field has a bad type -- it must be a JSON integer.